# Custom Font installation in Laravel TCPDF

Tags: laravel, pdf, tcpdf

I am trying to add custom unicode font(http://www.freebanglafont.com/catetory.php?b=173) with Laravel TCPDF. But it throwing error like
"TCPDF ERROR: Could not include font definition file:"

My controller code:

```
$pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);
$fontname = TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont(public_path().'/fonts/SolaimanLipi.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32);
$pdf->SetFont($fontname, '', 14, '', true);
$pdf->AddPage();
```

I have put my font in "public/fonts" and followed the documentation 
http://www.tcpdf.org/fonts.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try placing your font in the `tcpdf/fonts` folder or setting the `K_PATH_FONTS` constant to the location of your font. Either way, it is unnecessary (and probably unwise) to keep your font folder in the `public` folder.

Comment: What is the return value from `TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont()`? According to the docs, this method attempts to convert the provided font file and, if successful, copies it to the fonts folder (defined by `K_PATH_FONTS`). Perhaps the conversion is failing, in which case the method will return false, so you really need to check that, or the destination folder is not writable. If either of those things occur, your converted font will not end up in the fonts folder and you will get that error.

Answer (score 0):

Check the TCPDF tools folder, there is a script for adding font. You will find the instruction and example in convert_fonts_examples.txt.

1. First, copy the .ttf font file in tcpdf\tools\
2. In a terminal go to tcpdf\tools folder run the following code

> php tcpdf_addfont.php -b -t TrueTypeUnicode -i arial.ttf

3. Then, the script will notify you if the font was successfully added.

> >>> Converting fonts for TCPDF:
> *** Output dir set to ./TCPDF/fonts/
> +++ OK   : ./TCPDF/tools/arial.ttf added as arial
> >>> Process successfully completed!

Then in you project try to use the added font.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install / download / require the tcpdf library into your project.
2. Open the library folder (for example mine was: ./vendor/tecnickcom/tcpdf).
3. Notice and enter to the tools folder.
4. Copy the TTF file(s) into this tools folder.
5. Run this command from the terminal (still from the tools folder): $ PHP

   tcpdf_addfont -i BOOKOS.TTF (Replace BOOKOS.TTF with your own fonts)
6. Repeat step (5) for each fonts desired.

Coding time..
To change between fonts from your php code, use the following scripts.

```
$pdf->SetFont($font_family = ‘bookos’, $variant = ‘’, $fontsize = 11);
```